# Regular Expression that allows word characters and a few special characters but no commas

Tags: c#, regex

I have a viewmodel named "**Classification**" to be used in my MVC website.

I'm trying to validate a property named "**Description**" on this viewmodel using a regular expression attribute.

The requirements for this "**Description**" property are:

- Allows only the following characters:

  - Letters, numbers, spaces and any of the following characters _ -+ ( )
    /\

So, these values should pass the validation:

- test
- test1
- test1_
- t(e_ s)t1 i/s \good+-

And these should fail:

- t,test
- t.test
- test!
- te!@#$%st

This is the regular expression I have so far:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 _+-\/\\\(\)]+$
```

All the expected values above are passing, but the first two values in the should-fail list (the comma and period values) are passing as well, which is wrong!! This is very frustrating.

Please let me know what I have missed in my regular expression.

Thanks a lot in advance,

M

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the '-' dash in your character class

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9 _+\-\/\\\(\)]+$
```

without it you get:

> A character in the range between “+” and “/” «+-/»**

Comment: as a side note, at least in .Net regex, you *don't* need to escape the `()/` characters either. ...but it doesn't hurt

Comment: Grab yourself Expresso(http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) or RegexBuddy(http://www.regexbuddy.com/). I paid for RegexBuddy and never regretted it.

Comment: I actually downloaded Expresso just before I posted this question while trying to figure it out, I expected it to tell me what's wrong or at least show me the breakdown, but I only got this in the analyzer: "Any character in this class: [a-zA-Z0-9 _+-\/\\\(\)], one or more repitions"... which didn't help me. I may be missing the point of how to use it correctly in this case though.

Comment: Wow, that's awesome!! Very handy for deciphering existing expressions as well. Thanks for the tip!